# Path variables in AWS Step Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I'm trying to figure out a way to pass path variables in aws step functions for api gateway invocation.
I was able to pass query parameters as shown here:-
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-api-gateway.html

How do i pass path variables?

Edit 1: Adding more info : how do i pass path variable which i receive in the response from previous step ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just specify the full path string in `Path`. For example (other attributes are hidden for clarity):

```
{
    "Type": "Task", 
    "Resource":"arn:aws:states:::apigateway:invoke", 
    "Parameters": {
        "ApiEndpoint": "example.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
        "Path": "pet/5",
        ...
}
```

This will invoke:

```
example.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/pet/5
```

So that if you have configured your resource path as

```
/pet/{pet_id}
```

The value of path parameter `pet_id` will be `5`.

EDIT

Since OP explained the need to loop and call the API with different ID values, suggest to create a custom Lambda, and custom code the logic to loop through each ID and call the API. Or, you can code the loop to occur in the workflow itself. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-create-iterate-pattern-section.html.

Comment: What if the path id comes as a response from a previous step ?

Comment: In that case can you format such that the full path is the output from a previous step? Instead of just the path id. Then you can use the `.$` notation as in `"Path.$" : "$.path_from_previous_step"`.

Comment: actually i need to invoke the api multiple times with a range of path ids..

Comment: ok depending on the full use case, I think you can create a custom Lambda, and custom code the logic to loop through each ID and call the API. Or, you can code the loop to occur in the workflow itself. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-create-iterate-pattern-section.html.

Comment: I think Lambda fits my use case. If you could paste it as an answer i will accept it.

Comment: Alright edited the answer. Good luck with your use case!